# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/Session hibernate jars is set

Tags: java, hibernate, tomcat, servlets

I inherited several projects Javas in my new job, but I'm having some problems with settings. I'm facing a problem that is researched so common. "java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org / hibernate / Session", put all the jars even unnecessary hibernate are mapped in the classpath.

Im using tomcat 7, hirbernat 4, jre7.

every project extends compnet that have all necessary jars in lib folder.

do i need to put those already mapped jars in this project ?

The erro is catch here:

```
    @Override
public void init(ServletConfig config) throws ServletException {
    super.init(config);
    HibernateUtil.currentSession();
}
```

classpath:

```
<classpathentry kind="src" path="src"/>
<classpathentry exported="true" kind="con" path="org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.internal.module.container"/>
<classpathentry exported="true" kind="lib" path="/Compnet/lib/xstream 1.3/xpp3_min-1.1.4c.jar">
    <attributes>
        <attribute name="org.eclipse.jst.component.dependency" value="/WEB-INF/lib"/>
    </attributes>
</classpathentry>
<classpathentry exported="true" kind="lib" path="/Compnet/lib/xstream 1.3/xstream-1.3.1.jar">
    <attributes>
        <attribute name="org.eclipse.jst.component.dependency" value="/WEB-INF/lib"/>
    </attributes>
</classpathentry>
<classpathentry exported="true" kind="con" path="org.eclipse.jst.server.core.container/org.eclipse.jst.server.tomcat.runtimeTarget/Apache Tomcat v6.0"/>
<classpathentry exported="true" kind="lib" path="/Compnet/lib/commons fileupload 1.2.1/commons-fileupload-1.2.1.jar">
    <attributes>
        <attribute name="org.eclipse.jst.component.dependency" value="/WEB-INF/lib"/>
    </attributes>
</classpathentry>
<classpathentry exported="true" kind="lib" path="/Compnet/lib/hibernate 3/antlr.jar">
    <attributes>
        <attribute name="org.eclipse.jst.component.dependency" value="/WEB-INF/lib"/>
    </attributes>
</classpathentry>
<classpathentry exported="true" kind="lib" path="/Compnet/lib/hibernate 3/commons-collections.jar">
    <attributes>
        <attribute name="org.eclipse.jst.component.dependency" value="/WEB-INF/lib"/>
    </attributes>
</classpathentry>
<classpathentry exported="true" kind="lib" path="/Compnet/lib/hibernate 3/dom4j.jar">
    <attributes>
        <attribute name="org.eclipse.jst.component.dependency" value="/WEB-INF/lib"/>
    </attributes>
</classpathentry>
<classpathentry exported="true" kind="lib" path="/Compnet/lib/hibernate 3/ejb3-persistence.jar">
    <attributes>
        <attribute name="org.eclipse.jst.component.dependency" value="/WEB-INF/lib"/>
    </attributes>
</classpathentry>
<classpathentry exported="true" kind="lib" path="/Compnet/lib/hibernate 3/hibernate-annotations.jar">
    <attributes>
        <attribute name="org.eclipse.jst.component.dependency" value="/WEB-INF/lib"/>
    </attributes>
</classpathentry>
<classpathentry exported="true" kind="lib" path="/Compnet/lib/hibernate 3/hibernate-commons-annotations.jar">
    <attributes>
        <attribute name="org.eclipse.jst.component.dependency" value="/WEB-INF/lib"/>
    </attributes>
</classpathentry>
<classpathentry exported="true" kind="lib" path="/Compnet/lib/hibernate 3/hibernate-validator.jar">
    <attributes>
        <attribute name="org.eclipse.jst.component.dependency" value="/WEB-INF/lib"/>
    </attributes>
</classpathentry>
<classpathentry exported="true" kind="lib" path="/Compnet/lib/hibernate 3/hibernate3.jar">
    <attributes>
        <attribute name="org.eclipse.jst.component.dependency" value="/WEB-INF/lib"/>
    </attributes>
</classpathentry>
<classpathentry exported="true" kind="lib" path="/Compnet/lib/hibernate 3/javassist.jar">
    <attributes>
        <attribute name="org.eclipse.jst.component.dependency" value="/WEB-INF/lib"/>
    </attributes>
</classpathentry>
<classpathentry exported="true" kind="lib" path="/Compnet/lib/hibernate 3/jta.jar">
    <attributes>
        <attribute name="org.eclipse.jst.component.dependency" value="/WEB-INF/lib"/>
    </attributes>
</classpathentry>
<classpathentry exported="true" kind="lib" path="/Compnet/lib/hibernate 3/jtds-1.2.4.jar">
    <attributes>
        <attribute name="org.eclipse.jst.component.dependency" value="/WEB-INF/lib"/>
    </attributes>
</classpathentry>
<classpathentry exported="true" kind="lib" path="/Compnet/lib/hibernate 3/log4j.jar">
    <attributes>
        <attribute name="org.eclipse.jst.component.dependency" value="/WEB-INF/lib"/>
    </attributes>
</classpathentry>
<classpathentry exported="true" kind="lib" path="/Compnet/lib/hibernate 3/slf4j-api.jar">
    <attributes>
        <attribute name="org.eclipse.jst.component.dependency" value="/WEB-INF/lib"/>
    </attributes>
</classpathentry>
<classpathentry exported="true" kind="lib" path="/Compnet/lib/hibernate 3/slf4j-log4j12.jar">
    <attributes>
        <attribute name="org.eclipse.jst.component.dependency" value="/WEB-INF/lib"/>
    </attributes>
</classpathentry>
<classpathentry exported="true" kind="lib" path="/Compnet/lib/commons logging/commons-logging-1.1.1.jar">
    <attributes>
        <attribute name="org.eclipse.jst.component.dependency" value="/WEB-INF/lib"/>
    </attributes>
</classpathentry>
<classpathentry exported="true" kind="lib" path="/Compnet/lib/commons logging/commons-logging-adapters-1.1.jar">
    <attributes>
        <attribute name="org.eclipse.jst.component.dependency" value="/WEB-INF/lib"/>
    </attributes>
</classpathentry>
<classpathentry exported="true" kind="lib" path="/Compnet/lib/commons logging/commons-logging-api-1.1.jar">
    <attributes>
        <attribute name="org.eclipse.jst.component.dependency" value="/WEB-INF/lib"/>
    </attributes>
</classpathentry>
<classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER"/>
<classpathentry combineaccessrules="false" exported="true" kind="src" path="/pkg_ocorrencia"/>
<classpathentry combineaccessrules="false" exported="true" kind="src" path="/pkg_mandado"/>
<classpathentry exported="true" kind="lib" path="/Compnet/lib/jasper - ireport 3.7.4/commons-beanutils-1.8.2.jar">
    <attributes>
        <attribute name="org.eclipse.jst.component.dependency" value="/WEB-INF/lib"/>
    </attributes>
</classpathentry>
<classpathentry exported="true" kind="lib" path="/Compnet/lib/jasper - ireport 3.7.4/commons-digester-1.7.jar">
    <attributes>
        <attribute name="org.eclipse.jst.component.dependency" value="/WEB-INF/lib"/>
    </attributes>
</classpathentry>
<classpathentry exported="true" kind="lib" path="/Compnet/lib/jasper - ireport 3.7.4/groovy-all-1.5.5.jar">
    <attributes>
        <attribute name="org.eclipse.jst.component.dependency" value="/WEB-INF/lib"/>
    </attributes>
</classpathentry>
<classpathentry exported="true" kind="lib" path="/Compnet/lib/jasper - ireport 3.7.4/iText-2.1.0.jar">
    <attributes>
        <attribute name="org.eclipse.jst.component.dependency" value="/WEB-INF/lib"/>
    </attributes>
</classpathentry>
<classpathentry exported="true" kind="lib" path="/Compnet/lib/jasper - ireport 3.7.4/jasperreports-3.7.4.jar">
    <attributes>
        <attribute name="org.eclipse.jst.component.dependency" value="/WEB-INF/lib"/>
    </attributes>
</classpathentry>
<classpathentry exported="true" kind="lib" path="/Compnet/lib/jasper - ireport 3.7.4/jasperreports-chart-themes-3.7.4.jar">
    <attributes>
        <attribute name="org.eclipse.jst.component.dependency" value="/WEB-INF/lib"/>
    </attributes>
</classpathentry>
<classpathentry exported="true" kind="lib" path="/Compnet/lib/jasper - ireport 3.7.4/jasperreports-extensions-3.5.3.jar">
    <attributes>
        <attribute name="org.eclipse.jst.component.dependency" value="/WEB-INF/lib"/>
    </attributes>
</classpathentry>
<classpathentry exported="true" kind="lib" path="/Compnet/lib/jasper - ireport 3.7.4/jasperreports-fonts-3.7.4.jar">
    <attributes>
        <attribute name="org.eclipse.jst.component.dependency" value="/WEB-INF/lib"/>
    </attributes>
</classpathentry>
<classpathentry exported="true" kind="lib" path="/Compnet/lib/jasper - ireport 3.7.4/spring.jar">
    <attributes>
        <attribute name="org.eclipse.jst.component.dependency" value="/WEB-INF/lib"/>
    </attributes>
</classpathentry>
<classpathentry exported="true" kind="lib" path="/Compnet/lib/jasper - ireport 3.7.4/xalan.jar">
    <attributes>
        <attribute name="org.eclipse.jst.component.dependency" value="/WEB-INF/lib"/>
    </attributes>
</classpathentry>
<classpathentry exported="true" kind="lib" path="/Compnet/lib/jasper - ireport 3.7.4/jfreechart-1.0.12.jar">
    <attributes>
        <attribute name="org.eclipse.jst.component.dependency" value="/WEB-INF/lib"/>
    </attributes>
</classpathentry>
<classpathentry exported="true" kind="lib" path="/Compnet/lib/jasper - ireport 3.7.4/jcommon-1.0.15.jar">
    <attributes>
        <attribute name="org.eclipse.jst.component.dependency" value="/WEB-INF/lib"/>
    </attributes>
</classpathentry>
<classpathentry combineaccessrules="false" kind="src" path="/Compnet"/>
<classpathentry exported="true" kind="lib" path="/Compnet/lib/commons email 1.2/commons-email-1.2.jar"/>
<classpathentry kind="lib" path="D:/Tomcat 7/apache-tomcat-7.0.27/lib/servlet-api.jar"/>
<classpathentry kind="lib" path="/Compnet/lib/hibernate4/antlr-2.7.7.jar"/>
<classpathentry kind="lib" path="/Compnet/lib/hibernate4/c3p0-0.9.1.jar"/>
<classpathentry kind="lib" path="/Compnet/lib/hibernate4/dom4j-1.6.1.jar"/>
<classpathentry kind="lib" path="/Compnet/lib/hibernate4/ehcache-core-2.4.3.jar"/>
<classpathentry kind="lib" path="/Compnet/lib/hibernate4/hibernate-c3p0-4.1.4.Final.jar"/>
<classpathentry kind="lib" path="/Compnet/lib/hibernate4/hibernate-commons-annotations-4.0.1.Final.jar"/>
<classpathentry kind="lib" path="/Compnet/lib/hibernate4/hibernate-core-4.1.4.Final.jar"/>
<classpathentry kind="lib" path="/Compnet/lib/hibernate4/hibernate-ehcache-4.1.4.Final.jar"/>
<classpathentry kind="lib" path="/Compnet/lib/hibernate4/hibernate-entitymanager-4.1.4.Final.jar"/>
<classpathentry kind="lib" path="/Compnet/lib/hibernate4/hibernate-envers-4.1.4.Final.jar"/>
<classpathentry kind="lib" path="/Compnet/lib/hibernate4/hibernate-infinispan-4.1.4.Final.jar"/>
<classpathentry kind="lib" path="/Compnet/lib/hibernate4/hibernate-jpa-2.0-api-1.0.1.Final.jar"/>
<classpathentry kind="lib" path="/Compnet/lib/hibernate4/hibernate-proxool-4.1.4.Final.jar"/>
<classpathentry kind="lib" path="/Compnet/lib/hibernate4/infinispan-core-5.1.4.FINAL.jar"/>
<classpathentry kind="lib" path="/Compnet/lib/hibernate4/javassist-3.15.0-GA.jar"/>
<classpathentry kind="lib" path="/Compnet/lib/hibernate4/jboss-logging-3.1.0.GA.jar"/>
<classpathentry kind="lib" path="/Compnet/lib/hibernate4/jboss-marshalling-1.3.11.GA.jar"/>
<classpathentry kind="lib" path="/Compnet/lib/hibernate4/jboss-marshalling-river-1.3.11.GA.jar"/>
<classpathentry kind="lib" path="/Compnet/lib/hibernate4/jboss-transaction-api_1.1_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar"/>
<classpathentry kind="lib" path="/Compnet/lib/hibernate4/jgroups-3.0.9.Final.jar"/>
<classpathentry kind="lib" path="/Compnet/lib/hibernate4/proxool-0.8.3.jar"/>
<classpathentry kind="lib" path="/Compnet/lib/hibernate4/rhq-pluginAnnotations-3.0.4.jar"/>
<classpathentry kind="lib" path="/Compnet/lib/hibernate4/slf4j-api-1.6.1.jar"/>
<classpathentry kind="lib" path="/Compnet/lib/hibernate4/stax2-api-3.1.1.jar"/>
<classpathentry kind="lib" path="/Compnet/lib/hibernate4/woodstox-core-asl-4.1.1.jar"/>

<classpathentry kind="output" path="build/classes"/>
```

stacktrance:

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/Session
    at br.com.flex4j.servlet.genericActionServlet.init(genericActionServlet.java:29)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1161)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.allocate(StandardWrapper.java:806)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:129)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:175)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:128)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:263)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:844)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:584)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:447)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hibernate.Session
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1358)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1204)
    ... 13 more

Jun 21, 2012 3:39:22 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Allocate exception for servlet genericActionServlet
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hibernate.Session
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1358)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1204)
    at br.com.flex4j.servlet.genericActionServlet.init(genericActionServlet.java:29)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1161)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.allocate(StandardWrapper.java:806)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:129)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:175)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:128)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:263)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:844)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:584)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:447)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

EDIT:

ClassPath of my project: [image: properties>java build path]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From what I understand the classpath xml you provided is used by Eclipse, it has nothing to do with your web application classpath. The reason you get an NoClassDefFoundError is Tomcat not being able to find Hibernate class. Make sure your Web Module has all required jars in WEB-INF/lib directory.

Comment: @MalGaniS You Eclipse Project classpath is not related to classpath tomcat uses when it initializes your app.  Your jar files must be copied to Webcontent/WEB-INF folder if you want to start Tomcat from Eclipse. I believe there is some build script (ANT or so) which copies all dependencies into WEB-INF/lib folder of your war file.

Comment: oh damm.. i need to put those libs in my tomcat lib folder.. 3 years working with .NET made me forget this.. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Add all the JARS to WEB-INF and perform build path on project.

Answer (score 0):

To add jars in eclipse you have two options:

Right click on project got to 
properties-->click on java build path --> configure build path--> Libraries --> 
and select add external jars button. It will open a window where you can add all your jars required.

Second option is to paste jars directly to lib folder. lib folder is in Web Content --> WEB-INF --> lib.

Use any one of them.